# Display text live on Text widget while typing on another Text as input

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi I am a beginner to Python. How to display text live in tkinter Text widget while i am typing on another Text or Entry widget? Can i use root.after to keep getting the contents?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('600x400')

def display():
    tDisplay.config(text=tEnter.get(1.0, END))
    root.after(1000, display)


tDisplay = Text(root, height=2, width=20, padx=10, pady=10)
tDisplay.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

tEnter = Text(root, height=2, width=20, padx=10, pady=10)
tEnter.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


display()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can also use `after()` to get the contents, at the same time you should also delete the current item inside the text box so as to not keep adding to the textbox:

```
def display():
    tDisplay.delete('1.0','end')
    tDisplay.config(text=tEnter.get('1.0', 'end-1c'))
    root.after(1000, display)
```